# Best way to keep params in the uri for zf2

Tags: php, url, zend-framework2, parameters, viewhelper

So a user is directed to a page in my ZF2 app as follows:

> http://example.com/some/route/variable?auth=1234&channel=1234&tz=1234&locale=&client=1234

The controller loads a form:

```
if ($prg instanceof Response) {
    return $prg
} elseif ($prg === false) {

    return new ViewModel([
        'form' => $this->transferForm,
    ]);
}
```

And in the view:

```
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('some/route',[],true));
$form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
```

What I want to happen is when the user invokes the form that it posts to the same inbound route, namely:

> http://example.com/some/route/variable?auth=1234&channel=1234&tz=1234&locale=&client=1234

Is there a stupidly simple way of doing this?

Or do I need to get each param, and explicityly place them in the form target uri?:

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('some/route',[],[query => [''] ]));
```

As it stands I have written a helper to deal with this:

```
namespace Some\View\Helper;

use Zend\View\Helper\AbstractHelper;


class ParamsHelper extends AbstractHelper {

    public function __invoke()
    {
        $param1 = (isset($_GET['param1'])) ? $_GET['param1'] : '';
        $param2 = (isset($_GET['param2'])) ? $_GET['param2'] : '';
        $param3 = (isset($_GET['param3'])) ? $_GET['param3'] : '';
        $param4 = (isset($_GET['param4'])) ? $_GET['param4'] : '';
        $param5 = (isset($_GET['param5'])) ? $_GET['param5'] : '';

        $queryParams = (null == $auth) ? [] : ['query' =>
                                                   [
                                                       'param1' => $param1 ,
                                                       'param2' => $param2 ,
                                                       'param3' => $param3 ,
                                                       'param4' => $param4,
                                                       'param5' => $param5
                                                   ]
                                                ];

        return $queryParams;
    }

}
```

This resolves the issue however it still seems a longwinded and not so dynamic way of resolving the issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [`Url` view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html) but this helper does (surprisingly) not give you the full request url with query params. But there is also a `ServerUrl` helper in ZF2 and this one gives you the full url including query params if used like this:

in case of your example:

`http://example.com/some/route/variable?auth=1234&channel=1234&tz=1234&locale=&client=1234`

It will do the following:

```
$viewHelperManager = $serviceManager->get('ViewHelperManager');

$urlHelper = $viewHelper->get('url');
$serverUrlHelper = $viewHelper->get('serverUrl');

$urlHelper(); // --> /some/route/variable
$serverUrlHelper(true); // --> http://example.com/some/route/variable?auth=1234&channel=1234&tz=1234&locale=&client=1234
```

In your view simply as follows:

```
$this->url(); // --> /some/route/variable
```

and

```
$this->serverUrl(); // --> http://example.com/some/route/variable?auth=1234&channel=1234&tz=1234&locale=&client=1234
```

---

**Note** *There [are actually more people who complain](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6632) about not being able to reuse query params in the url view helper. On that page there is also a link to an alternative (refactored) `Url` helper class that does reuse query params.*